# URL encryption in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to encrypt the url in codeigniter.

My ultimate goal is encrypt everything after the domain.
example.com/controller/function/itemid
to
example.com/sdfsdfsff/sdafaergdfsd/dfesDEWrewF

I can use the ci's "encrypt" library in my controller to encyrpt/decrypt the itemid but is there any other way to do encyrtpt everything in the url?

Comment: You might wanna look into hooks. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using hooks might be simply overriding the `CI_URI` and `CI_Config` classes.  When loading the URI segments into the segment array, it should decrypt them (probably in the `_set_uri_string()` method).  It should then encrypt the segments in an overridden `CI_Config` class (the `_uri_string()` method, specifically).

Here's an (untested) sample for your enjoyment:

```
<?php
// application/core/MY_URI.php
class MY_URI extends CI_URI {
    function _set_uri_string($str)
    {
        parent::_set_uri_string($str);
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('encrypt');
        $parts = explode('/', $this->uri_string);
        foreach ($parts as &$part)
        {
            if ($part) $part = $CI->encrypt->decode($part);
        }
        $this->uri_string = implode('/', $parts);
    }
}

// application/core/MY_Config.php
class MY_Config extends CI_Config {
    protected function _uri_string($uri)
    {
        if ( !is_array($uri))
        {
            $uri = explode('/', $uri);
        }

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('encrypt');
        foreach ($uri as &$part)
        {
            if ($part) $part = $CI->encrypt->encode($part);
        }

        return parent::_uri_string($uri);
    }
}
```